# Python extension modules без линковки к pythonXX.dll

Tags: c++, python, windows, dll, link

Возможно ли использовать импортируемые dll (имеющие расширение .pyd) в питоне на Windows без линковки к pythonXX.dll? Например, всем .pyd модулям в директории DLLs последнего релиза требуется python37.dll (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/).

Другими словами, python37.dll это та же библиотека, что и libs/python37.lib, к которой можно прилинковаться статически?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом нет смысла. Модули pyd - это тоже динамические библиотеки, которые будут загружены в адресное пространство процесса python.exe, куда уже была загружена при запуске python37.dll. Зачем тащить в память ещё одну копию? Кроме того, python37.lib - это не статическая библиотека, а *библиотека импорта*, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Да, сейчас порылся с помощью Process Monitor - действительно, эта dll загружается при старте python.exe.

Comment: И да, python37.lib не статическая